# The type or namespace name could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET. So I was following this tutorial http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/ and came up with a problem.

As the walkthrough, I added the markup on .ascx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserInfoBoxControl" %>
<b>Information about <%= this.UserName  %></b>
<%= this.UserName %> is <%= this.UserAge %> years old and lives in <%= this.UserCountry %>
<My:UserInfoBoxControl runat="server" ID="MyUserInfoBoxControl" />
```

And I've declared the properties in code-behind file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace VeryBasic
{
public partial class UserInfoBoxControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string userName;
    private int userAge;
    private string userCountry;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    public int UserAge
    {
        get { return userAge; }
        set { userAge = value; }
    }

    public string UserCountry
    {
        get { return userCountry; }
        set { userCountry = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Then to add this user control I've created a form and added the code as below. (To be sure I dragged and dropped the user control to the web form and edited.)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="VeryBasic.WebForm" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx" TagPrefix="My" TagName="UserInfoBoxControl" %>
<My:UserInfoBoxControl runat="server" ID="MyUserInfoBoxControl" UserName="John Doe" UserAge="45" UserCountry="Australia" />
```

and the code-behind of the web form is here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace VeryBasic
{
public partial class WebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // These values can come from anywhere, but right now, we just hardcode them
        MyUserInfoBoxControl.UserName = "Jane Doe";
        MyUserInfoBoxControl.UserAge = 33;
        MyUserInfoBoxControl.UserCountry = "Germany";
    }
}
}
```

As for the tutorial I can run the project. But here I'm getting an error.

**Error 3   The type or namespace name 'UserInfoBoxControl' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

I tried my best to explain the error I got.Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the namespace name from very basic to 'userinfoboxcontrol'

Comment: I solved the error. I've entered data in both markup and code-behind file mistakenly. It was the reason I got the error. Anyway Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

2 mistakes in the code.

1. Properties like `UserName`, `UserAge` are not static. So you have to create instance of `MyUserInfoBoxControl` to access them.

   `MyUserInfoBoxControl obj = new MyUserInfoBoxControl();
   obj.UserName = "Jane Doe";`
2. I guess you can right click on `MyUserInfoBoxControl`, whick is giving error and select `Resolve` option. Use resolve trick to find namespace as it is difficult to remember which class is in which namespace.